# Python detect direct method call

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
a = A()
a.foo(123)
A.foo(a, 123)
```

How can I detect which line caused foo() execution: 2 or 3? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why do you want/need to?

Comment: create print statements before each to see in what order it was executed

Comment: Both of them are calling the same function, you can use the inspect module to inspect the stack frame and tell which one caused it but those aren't the only 2 ways this function can be called.

Comment: @dskrypa task in university

Comment: Honestly, it's not a great question from the professor.  In general, it shouldn't matter which form was used.  The [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module may help, but changing behavior (why else would it matter) based on this does not really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: There are very few use cases where the difference between these is actually important.  Having different behavior based on whether a method is called directly on an instance or by explicitly passing the instance to the method accessed through the class would likely violate the [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

This solution uses the fact that we can tell whether a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) was accessed through an instance or through a class by whether the `instance` parameter is None or not.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from functools import partial
from typing import Optional, Type


class Method:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance: Optional[B], owner: Type[B]):
        via_instance = instance is not None
        if via_instance:
            return partial(self.func, instance, via_instance=via_instance)
        else:
            return partial(self.func, via_instance=via_instance)


class B:
    @Method
    def foo(self, bar, via_instance):
        if via_instance:
            return 'via instance'
        return 'via class'
```

Test:

```py
>>> b = B()

>>> b.foo(123)
'via instance'

>>> B.foo(b, 123)
'via class'
```

It may still be technically possible to work around this detection, but this approach is not as hacky/brittle as the one below that uses `inspect`.

---

## Alternate Solution

Note: This solution over-complicates the problem.  This is extremely hacky, and there are many other cases that this does not cover.  This guesses based on the defined parameters of this question.  It is not definitive.

```py
import ast
import inspect
from ast import Assign, Call, Expr

class A:
    def foo(self, bar):
        code = inspect.stack()[1].code_context[0]
        parsed = ast.parse(code).body[0]
        if isinstance(parsed, Assign):
            parsed = parsed.value
        if isinstance(parsed, Expr):
            parsed = parsed.value
        if not isinstance(parsed, Call):
            raise TypeError(f'Unexpected type={type(parsed)} for {parsed=}')
        if len(parsed.args) == 1:
            return 'via instance'
        return 'via class'
```

Test:

```py
>>> a = A()

>>> a.foo(123)
'via instance'

>>> A.foo(a, 123)
'via class'
```

There are many other ways that the method could be called, and this approach is not guaranteed to catch all of them.  Some examples of other ways :

- `super().foo(123)` in a subclass
- `foo = partial(A.foo, bar=123); foo(a)`
- `foo = partial(A.foo, a); foo(123)`
- `args = (a, 123); A.foo(*args)`
- etc...